# Automatically restart a new input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to think that if you do something in the first id = "benodigheden" that there is something specific then a second rule is for id = "benodigheden" I also couldn't find anything on the internet. I think you need to have java but here is my knowledge still too small for.
I hope somebody can help me.

This is my HTML:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
<legend>Neem contact op</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Naam">Naam: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Naam" name="Naam" placeholder="Naam" required="required" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Email">Email :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" id="Email"name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Seizoen">Seizoen: </label>
        </td>
        <td>                                                                  
            <select name="Seizoen" id="Seizoen" required>
            <option value="">Kies hier je seizoen</option>
                <option value="Lente">Lente</option>
                <option value="Zomer">Zomer</option>
                <option value="Herfst">Herfst</option>
                <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <hr />  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="benodigheden1">Benodigheden:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="benodigheden1"name="benodigheden1" placeholder="Benodigheden" required="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="ingrediënten1">Ingrediënten:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="ingrediënten1"name="ingrediënten1" placeholder="Ingrediënten" required="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="stappenplan">Stappenplanm:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="stappenplan" id="stappenplan" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Stappenplan" required="required" /></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Opmerking">Opmerking:</label>
            </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="Opmerking" id="Opmerking" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Opmerking" required="required" /></textarea>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Verzenden" name="Verzenden" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okdx4t8z/5/).

Comment: Do you want this to happen after the form is sent?

Comment: You misspelled Benodigdheden

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking, but I doubt you would need Java.

Comment: @William please make the question understandable.

Comment: NB: The fiddle does not have all of the inputs the in-line code has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want an extra line (rule?) to appear once you enter text in it, and that this should happen for those inputs that have a sequence number in their `id`.

For this I suggest you include `jQuery` and add a script that detects input changes, and adds a new input if needed, with the next available sequence number:

```
$(document).on('keyup change input', 'input, textarea', function() {
    if (!$(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
        // no text entered, so don't add line
        return;
    }
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Extract name and linenumber from id
    var res = id.split(/(\d+$)/);
    if (res.length < 2) {
        // No line number, so don't add line
        return;
    }
    var newId = res[0] + (parseInt(res[1]) + 1);
    if ($('#' + newId).length) {
        // Not the last line, so don't add line
        return;
    }
    // Add a line, and make it non-mandatory
    $(this).clone()
        .attr('id', newId).removeAttr('required')
        .val('')
        .insertAfter(this)
        .before($('<br>'));
});
```

Although the above can be done in pure `javascript` it is much more cumbersome, and harder to deal with cross-browser issues.

You can see it work in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okdx4t8z/6/).

Comment: It is now also possible to send this with php (mail).  I hope you can help me.

Comment: @William, if you have a follow-up question, please create a new question about that. This way you will draw the attention of people who are skilled in working with php mail. In the mean while, if you consider that my contribution is a solution for your original question, then please accept it. Thanks.